# Working of the [0-9]

Tags: shell, wildcards

I am learning the shell commands and came across the short tags eg.[0-9],[[:digit:]] etc.. As a proof of concept i tried deleting all the files with the rm command(i know its not a good practise but i am trying to understand how things work),like this

```
rm [0-9].txt
```

there were two files in the directory 0.txt and 9.txt and it deleted the files 0.txt and 9.txt .I guessed that the expression [0-9] is expanded and then read as 0.txt 1.txt 2.txt .... However when you try only 
rm 5.txt,and the file does not exist, an error is thrown..

someone please tell me how the shorthand commands work when used with rm or ls.

Comment: If you had exactly these 10 files, you could do `rm {0..9}.txt` and get error for non-existing files.

Answer (score -1):

[0-9].txt is a regular expression and when expanded, means, one or more instances of files with extensions of .txt and names of single digit between 0 thru 9. It doesn't mean that you have to have all 10 files. If you have none, you will get an error message but it fyou at least have one file matching this pattern, your command will complete successfully.

Comment: by the way, in unix variants, unlike old DOS or IBM convention of file naming, there is no concept of extensions. I just referred to the part of file name as "extension" for the ease of reference. FYI.